# Protractor/Selenium -> how to check that a value put to the table was trimmed of whitespaces after saving my changes?

Tags: selenium, automation, protractor

I have a table where I put some values. The issue is that these values are trimmed of whitespaces after saving and I need to test this somehow.

For example I enter value

```
'  Test   '
```

and then when I click 'SAVE' button the value is trimmed by system to

```
'Test'
```

How to check it out in Selenium/Protractor that the final value after saving my changes is trimmed?
getText() returns already an inner text...
Can somebody please help with that?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **NO**.

However, you have other options, such as `BrowserUp Proxy`, `browsermob-proxy`.

For example, You can start a proxy and let all Selenium requests go through it, so you can capture requests and validate them (including parameters).

> Visit [browserup-proxy](https://github.com/browserup/browserup-proxy) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I think `.getAttribute('innerText');` is what you're looking for/

`.getText()` get the text value of the element as you see it displayed in the UI. innerText returned unmodified and untrimmed string